# Array types with <example> tag not working with Swagger (swashbuckle.aspnetcore)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I am using the summary and example tags for the swagger documentation.
I have a problem with the tag, it's not recognized by swagger when I use array :

I use swashbuckle.aspnetcore package Nuget.

Example :

```
[DataContract]
    public class HeaderResponse
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Statut code
        /// </summary>
        ///<example>400</example>
        [DataMember]
        public int StatusCode { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Title
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>Erreur sur methode1</example>
        [DataMember]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// List of errors 
        /// </summary>
        ///<example>["entry1", "entry2", "entry3"]</example>
        [DataMember]
        public List<string> ErrorList { get; } = new List<string>();
}
```

On swagger documentation, array is not interpreted :

[image]

I found others solutions by using ISchemaFilter like this :

```
public class SwaggerExcludeFilter : ISchemaFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
        {
            switch (context.Type.Name)
            {
                case "HeaderResponse":
                    foreach (var property in schema.Properties)
                    {
                        if (property.Value.Type == "array")
                        {
                            var array = new OpenApiArray();
                            array.Add(new OpenApiString("item1"));
                            array.Add(new OpenApiString("item2"));
                            array.Add(new OpenApiString("item3"));

                            property.Value.Example = array;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there no other way than to use ISchemaFilter to handle tags of type array?

Answer (score 2):

The quotes must be escaped using `&quot;`

```
/// <summary>
/// List of errors 
/// </summary>
///<example>[&quot;entry1&quot;,&quot;entry2&quot;,&quot;entry3&quot;]</example>
[DataMember]
public List<string> ErrorList { get; } = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Support for examples using XML comments on arrays was added in Swashbuckle.AspNetCore version 6.0.0.

It's mentioned in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1676#issuecomment-760508083) and their [documentation](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#include-descriptions-from-xml-comments) shows the following example:

```
/// <summary>
/// The sizes the product is available in
/// </summary>
/// <example>["Small", "Medium", "Large"]</example>
public List<string> Sizes { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do like this:

```
public List<string> ErrorList { get; } = new List<string>{"entry1", "entry2", "entry3"};
```

or:

```
[DataContract]
public class HeaderResponse
{
    public HeaderResponse()
    {
        ErrorList = new List<string> {"entry1", "entry2", "entry3" };
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Statut code
    /// </summary>
    ///<example>400</example>
    [DataMember]
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Title
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>Erreur sur methode1</example>
    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// List of errors 
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public List<string> ErrorList { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a demo:

```
[HttpPost("TestPar")]
        public IActionResult TestPar(HeaderResponse h)
        {
            return Json(h);
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Ok thanks, it's working but I would prefer not to do this by initializing properties or by constructor. I hope so there is another solution by using ISchemaFilter :)

Comment: The problem with this solution is the scenario where your client doesn't submit a value for the error list property instead of getting null or an empty array you'll have the populated array which then means if you needed a not empty validator it now has to interrogate the contents and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I try this. you can add a condition on the name of the property and add the null return in order not to lose the example on the other properties. But the best solution would be to be able to find a generic solution. How is it possible to get the example tag and the property name with ISchemaFilter ? This is my solution :

```
public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
{
    schema.Example = GetExampleOrNullFor(schema, context);
}

private IOpenApiAny GetExampleOrNullFor(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
{

switch (context.Type.Name)
{
    case "MyClass":
        foreach (var property in schema.Properties)
        {
            //Array property, which wraps its elements
            if (property.Value.Type == "array")
            {
                if (property.Key == "MyProperty1")
                {
                    var array = new OpenApiArray();
                    array.Add(new OpenApiString("item1"));
                    array.Add(new OpenApiString("item2"));
                    property.Value.Example = array;
                }
                else if (property.Key == "MyProperty2")
                {
                    var array = new OpenApiArray();
                    array.Add(new OpenApiString("item1"));
                    property.Value.Example = array;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    default:
        return null;
}

}
```